# Need of Transaction SIGnature (TSIG) record

Tags: authentication, dns, server

Can't we simply send the shared secret key along with AXFR query?

A hacker can easily use sniffed TSIG record to authenticate himself. Then how it's called SECURED zone transfer?

Comment: The point of a signature is that you sign the data *without* revealing the secret. An attacker listening on the wire will not be able to learn anything about the secret from observing the data and its signature.

Comment: I mean, the goal is not to prevent anyone from accessing your data, it is to prevent malicious parties from understanding it. A bunch of nonsensical bytes is just that if you don't have the secret that goes with it. So no, obviously always hide the secret, never ever send it.